# how do i use user-extensions in selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

If I remove '.sample' from file user-extensions.js how can I use the sample functions in a java file?

EG 
Selenium.prototype.doTypeRepeated

I think it needs to work with the WebDriver but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own code in Java with Webdriver or Selenium:

```
public void doTypeRepeated(String locator,String text) {

    String valueToType = text + text;
    driver.findElement(By.id(locator)).sendKeys(valueToType);

};
```

I suggest you learn how to use WebDriver in JUnit 4. (and also Java basics)

Comment: this is not an answer to the question as this is not using user-extensions

Comment: Its an answer to the above lying question > Progressive abstraction. Yes, you will have to spend some time.